# Dynamic array of template objects in C++

Tags: c++, templates, new-operator, delete-operator

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> *list = new vector<int>[33];
    delete[] list;
    return 0;
}
```

Any reason why the delete SIGSEGVs?

Comment: Compiles, links and runs for me - what platform?

Comment: I think you need to provide more code. There's nothing wrong with what you've posted.

Comment: By nothing wrong we mean the program is well-formed. Why you need  dynamic array of vectors, while not using a vector, who knows. :) (We need more code, and a probably a bigger picture.)

Comment: Any chance that the allocation failed and delete[] tried to access memory that it has no right to? Also, why not use vector of vectors of ints (vector< vector<int> >) instead, as GMan suggested?

Comment: @pnt: `operator new` throws an exception when allocation fails, there wouldn't be a segfault.

Comment: @GMan: More than just well-formed; `int main() { delete new int[3]; }` is well-formed but still wrong.

Comment: @Roger: That invokes UB, though, while OP doesn't.

Comment: @GMan: Exactly, being well-formed doesn't say whether UB is involved or not.

Comment: @Roger: Oh, I see what you're saying, got it.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter if the type is a template or not.  The compiler will expand the code to a normal type.  Deleting an array created with `new[]` you always use `delete[]`.

The code you pasted is a little unusual but technically valid.